# Why react-native do not use html tags but native tags like 'view' 'tab' and so on

Tags: react-native

I have a question, why `react-native` supports tagnames such as like `View` but not `Div`? `Html` tags are more familiar to  the `Html5` developers. Why not `Html` tags?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because the JSX tags are mapping onto native components. A `<View>` is a native component that you could conceptualize as a `<div>`. It can be styled as a container for any other content or components, a lot like a `<div>`. It's important to remember developing for React Native isn't the same as web development. You get some familiar styling from CSS, such as flex box, but you aren't actually rendering into a DOM. Read more about Views here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I am still confused. Most developers who interested in React Native are Javascript Developers. They almost have no experience in developing native applications. They have to learn tags like 'View' 'Navigator' and so on. I know that there is no real DOM in React Native app, I think just modifying 'View' to 'Div' will make building app more comfortable for Javascript Developers. After Changing, the new tag 'Div' that equals 'View' is still not real DOM tagname.

Comment: You're right that it makes a beginner have to learn new tags and such. One thing though is you could create your own library of Components that serve almost as aliases for conventional HTML tags. For example, you could just make a `<Div>` component that you import that simply returns a `<View>`. You could go further with this and make `<Span>` tags too! That would be a really cool project I would use and support!